# UWP Webview only triggers NavigationCompleted event for the last request

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I have a foreach loop to call `_webView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(url[index], resolver)` many times. As I know each time I navigate to a specific URL, the events `NavigationStarting` and `NavigationCompleted` are triggered. But in my case, `NavigationStarting` is called for every request but `NavigationCompleted` only trigger for the last request. 
I want to know Is there a way to make sure `NavigationCompleted` is called for every request. I searched but there is no answer meet my purpose.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
// here I raise event to call `NavigateToLocalStreamUri` of _webview
}
```

_webview have 2 events `NavigationStarting` and `NavigationCompleted`

// when `i = 0 or 1`
the program only calls event handler of `NavigationStarting`, but not call event handler of `NavigationCompleted`

// when `i = 2` (always, the last iteration of `for` loop)
the program calls event handler of both events `NavigationStarting` and `NavigationCompleted`

// Is there any solution to make sure when i = 0 or 1, `NavigationCompleted` handler is called?

Comment: If you start next navigation request before previous one completes, then previous one will never complete and therefore will not trigger NavigationCompleted. Seems like by calling `NavigateToLocalStreamUri` in a loop you do exactly that.

Comment: The completed event handle should work well. Please provide necessary code snippet to let us reproduce your issue.

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin what you said is exactly what I met. Do you have solution for this?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT, I updated my code snippet, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue. The issue is caused by the `for` loop continue before the previous navigation completed.

The key point to resolve this is to wait for the previous `NavigationCompleted` event handle occurred.You could use [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) which notifies a waiting thread that an event has occurred. For example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();        
    urls = new List<Uri>();
    waitForNavComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    urls.Add(...); 
}

List<Uri> urls;
AutoResetEvent waitForNavComplete;
private async void btnnavigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        mywebview.Navigate(urls[i]);
        await Task.Run(() => { waitForNavComplete.WaitOne(); });
    }
}
private void mywebview_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Uri.ToString());
    waitForNavComplete.Set();
}
```

Using [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx) method to set the state of the completed event to signaled so that `for` loop will stop waiting and continue.

Comment: thank you for your support, I will check you solution

Answer (score 1):

I think @sunteen-wu-msft's solution is a bit complicated. Sloppy use of `AutoResetEvent` can lead to a lot of headache. If the goal is to let `NavigationCompleted` to fire, then why not just navigate to the next URL when first one is completed, e.g. call `NavigateToLocalStreamUri` in the `NavigationCompleted` itself:

```
private Stack<Uri> toNavigate = ...

private void mywebview_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // Handle NavigationCompleted
    ...  
    // Navigate to the next Uri
    var uri = toNavigate.Pop();
    mywebview.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(uri, resolver);
}
```

Another option would be to simply create several webviews and navigate them all to different Uris. This can take quite a lot of resources though since all loaded websites will live in memory until you kill its webview.

Comment: tks you, I will take a look your solution. Yes, create several webviews seems a bad idea.