# Can't handle WebView Navigation

Tags: uwp

The problem can be a bit strange, but i need to execute NavigationCompleted() method before Test() method ends:

```
public Test()
       {
           WebView wb = new WebView(WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess);
           wb.Navigate(new Uri(@"Url"));
           wb.NavigationCompleted += NavigationCompleted;
       }
       private async void NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
       {

           //some stuff
       }
```

I can't use Thread.Sleep() in Test() Method because in this case the WebView can't do it's stuff, and therefore NavigationCompleted() will be called only after the Test () method is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398232/uwp-webview-only-triggers-navigationcompleted-event-for-the-last-request) to use [AutoResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=net-5.0) to wait for the NavigationCompleted event handler occurred. As follows:

```
   public AutoResetEvent waitForNavComplete;       
        public async void test()
        {
            waitForNavComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            mywebView.Navigate(new Uri(..));     
            mywebView.NavigationCompleted += MywebView_NavigationCompleted;
            await Task.Run(() => waitForNavComplete.WaitOne());
       
        }

        private void MywebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
         ……
            waitForNavComplete.Set();
        }
```